# How can I handle any data changed in my vue component?

Tags: vue.js, watch

I know I can 'watch' particular properties in my `data` changing in vue, but is it possible to handle *any* part of my component's data changing?

For example, I have:

```
data() {
   return {
     myProp: false,
     myOtherProp: true
   }
}
```

I can add a watch like so:

```
 watch: {
    "myProp": function(val, oldVal) {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

And could add one for `myOtherProp` too, but in reality I have many many properties, how do I add one handler for all?

### Further Context

The end-goal here is to detect a 'dirty' state so I can determine whether to warn the user they're potentially going to lose unsaved changes or not.

### What I've Tried

I know I could probably combine all my properties in data into one type, and just watch that, but it's too disruptive a change at the moment, too much risk. I'm intrigued into whether a global handler is possible anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to make a `computed` property, when this property changed you can call your function:

```
computed: {
    hash () {
      return `${this.myProp}
          |${this.myOtherProp}
   }
},
watch: {
   "hash": function(val, oldVal) {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clever! I like it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if myProp is an object with nested properties, you can return JSON.stringify(this.myProp) in the hash function and compare against that in the watch function.